# Which one is the correct YOLOv4 total loss function formula?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I couldn't find the total loss function in the main YOLOv4 paper. However, I found two differing formulas from two different papers (difference is highlighted/marked in the images below). **Which formula is the correct default total loss formula for YOLOv4?**

**FORMULA 1** - [Source](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4395/11/3/476)
[image: FORMULA 1]

---

**FORMULA 2** - [Source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1820/1/012163/pdf)
[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer. But in grepping the Darknet source code, there seems to be a lot of mention of loss in yolo_layer.c. Would the source code tell you which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Formula 1** is the more correct one because that term of the formula is the confidence loss when there is an object detected. And the confidence loss is based on the cross entropy error.